# Does this mean the zero matrix is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb C)$ with 
$D = \begin{bmatrix} 
A & A \\
0 & A \end{bmatrix} \in M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$.
Show that $D$ is diagonalizable iff $A=0$.

This question perplexes me. Given that D is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ for example, does that not mean that by definition there are $2n$ unique eigenvalues. However if $D=0$ then $\chi_{D}=\lambda^{2n}$? Something does not add up.

Comment: Of course $0$ is diagonalizable - it's _diagonal_.

Comment: That's one direction Sir Ullrich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Given that D is diagonalizable over C for example, does that not mean that by definition there are 2n unique eigenvalues."

No. It can be only one eigenvalue. For example, $I$ (the identity matrix) is clearly diagonalizable (already diagonal), but has only the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: But would I be correct in saying that every $\chi_{M}$ with unique eigenvalues in $\mathbb C$ is diagonalizable without looking at the minimal polynomial. I suppose because the minimal polynomial would be the same. Self-explanatory I suppose

Comment: Yes, if all eigenvalues are different, then the matrix is diagonalizable, it's quite obvious. But it's neary equally obviuous in this case that the minimal polynomial is equal to the characteristic one.

Answer (score 2):

A diagonalisable matrix  can have repeated eigenvalues. A criterion for a matrix to be diagonalisable is that it's *minimal polynomial* has only simple roots, and the null matrix has $x$ as its minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

"Given that D is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ for example, does that not mean that by definition there are $2n$ unique eigenvalues."

No, what you mean to say is that there are $2n$ **linearly independent** (*not* unique) **eigenvectors** (*not* eigenvalues).

Comment: If the eigenvalues are unique, does that not mean that there will be at least the same number of unique eigenspaces???

Comment: Each eigenvalue has an eigenspace of dimension at least 1. So if You have $n$ different eigenvalues, You have $n$ different eigenspaces which all are exactly one-dimensional because eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are linear independent.